# How remove duplicate letters using php

Tags: php

i want to remove duplicate letters ("tteeeessst stttringgg" => "test string").
Is there a short way that php can do that?

Comment: Do you mean multiple letters?

Comment: Remove duplicate words or letters?

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need to do that? It just already sounds like you picked the wrong solution to some problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$str = 'tteeeessst stttringgg';
echo preg_replace('{(.)\1+}','$1',$str);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/x0A7uBWM)

Comment: How can I delete the characters in this string : "tteeeessst stttringgg ççççğğğğ üüüü İİİÇÇÇ şşşşşş"

Comment: Just to be sure, do you want to delete the extra characters following *test string* or remove duplicates from those as well?

Comment: i want to get back to string : "test string çğ ü İÇ ş"

Comment: before your function start add "mb_strtolower" and "iconv('UTF-8', 'iso-8859-9', $str);" it works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to remove duplicate letters... this will remove the dups in words like "letter" though, so be careful....

```
$str = 'aabbccaaaaaddee';
echo preg_replace('{(.)\1+}','$1',$str);
//abcade
```

gotten from http://randomdrake.com/2008/04/10/php-and-regex-replacing-repeating-characters-with-single-characters-in-a-string/